# Is there anyway to acquire a crate key in Team Fortress 2 Beta?

Tags: team-fortress-2-beta

I have 20 crates from drops in Team Fortress 2 Beta and I obviously need keys to open them. I can't find any way to get keys in TF2 Beta but there may be one. Is there is a way? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 2):

Since the store is unavailable, and neither in-game trading nor Steam cross-game trading is available, there is no way to get keys in the beta.